# Private cache in symfony 2 does not generate

Tags: php, symfony, caching, http-caching

I am trying to use HTTP cache for my application but every time i set the cache to private, it does not apear in the app/cache folder.

For public cache everything is ok, the files/folders are being generated.

Is it something that i'm missing? I am trying to generate cache for a section of my website that requires authentication. So the cache should be specific for every username because it countains reports only for that user.

This is what i am doing:

```
    $response = $this->render('myTemplate.html.twig', array(
        'username' => $username
    ));

    $response->setMaxAge(600);
    $response->setPrivate();

    return $response;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony's http cache acts as a public (shared) reverse proxy server. That means it only caches public responses.

Read [Public vs Private Responses](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html#public-vs-private-responses) in Symfony docs:

> Both gateway and proxy caches are considered "shared" caches as the
>   cached content is shared by more than one user. If a user-specific
>   response were ever mistakenly stored by a shared cache, it might be
>   returned later to any number of different users. Imagine if your
>   account information were cached and then returned to every subsequent
>   user who asked for their account page!
>
> To handle this situation, every response may be set to be public or
>   private:
>
> - public: Indicates that the response may be cached by both private and
>     shared caches;
> - private: Indicates that all or part of the response
>     message is intended for a single user and must not be cached by a
>     shared cache.
>
> Symfony conservatively defaults each response to be
>   private. To take advantage of shared caches (like the Symfony reverse
>   proxy), the response will need to be explicitly set as public.

Comment: I Understand but I am also confused. What can I do to cache private, content specific pages?

Comment: You shouldn't. Private cache is the browsers' cache. Technically, it is possible to configure reverse proxies like Varnish this way, but that should be avoided (since it would generate a new document for each user). I suggest you read http://tomayko.com/writings/things-caches-do and https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/. I think you're trying to use http cache in scenario when other types of cache would work better. Also, remember you can use ESI to cache shared parts of the page.

Comment: But from what I understand, ESI is also public.

Comment: Yes, but you can have a private page with parts of a page publicaly cached (via ESI).

Comment: won't this alow a client to request sections of a page from another client?